# PHP adding to cart and modal display empty

Tags: php, modal-dialog, e-commerce, product, cart

I am new PHP. I am building e-commerce site. In shopping cart. if i try to add to cart from the product its added. modal nothing display. second its added. modal display successfully. Now i want to display modal when i click on add to cart from the product.
Total Stock: 15

URL: https://www.bellastudio.pk/new/products.php?p_slug=embroidery-shalwar-dupatta-2

Here is Insert cart.php Thank you in advance

**PHP**

```
$stmt = $host->prepare("SELECT * FROM productstock INNER JOIN product ON product.p_id = productstock.pid INNER JOIN productsize ON productsize.sid = productstock.size_id WHERE product.p_itemno = :itemno AND productsize.sname = :size");
$stmt->bindValue(':itemno', $itemno);
$stmt->bindValue(':size', $size);
$stmt->execute();
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    if($qty <= $row['stockqty']){

        if($qty == 0)
        {
            echo "<p>Please enter a quantity</p>";
        }else
        {
            $product = array("name" => $name,
                                "price" => $price,
                                "item_no" => $itemno,
                                "qty" => $qty,
                                "color" => $color,
                                "size" => $size,
                                "stockitemno" => $stockitemno,
                                "sleeves" => $sleeves,
                                "neck" => $neck,
                                "stockqty" => $row['stockqty']);     
// check if product is already in array - if it is just update quantity
            if(count($_SESSION['cart']) > 0)
            {
                foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $cart)
                {
                    if(in_array($stockitemno, $cart))
                    {
                        $exists = 1;
                        $check = $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty'] + $qty;

                        // add qty in cart with qty from post together
                        // then check if the total is equal to or less
                        // than your stockqty - if yes add qty together‚

                        if($check <= $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['stockqty']){
                            $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty'] += $qty;
                        } 
                        
                        break;
                   }
                }
            }
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $cart)
                {
                    if($_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty'] >= $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['stockqty'])
                   {
                      echo "No More Stock";
                   }else
                   {
    echo $name . ' (' . $size . ')';
        echo "<br />";
     echo "<p>was successfully added to your shopping cart</p>";
                   }
                }
           // if exists = 1
            if($exists !== 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['cart'][] = $product;
            }
}
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>The Requested quantity for this product is not available.</p>";
    }
        
    }  
        } catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$host = null; 

$cart_count = count($_SESSION['cart']);


 ?>
```

**Ajax**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
function load_cart_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"asset/includes/fetch_cart1.php",
            method:"POST",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('.cart_details').html(data);
                $('.badge1').text(data.total_item);
            }
        });
    }
$(document).on('click','#add_to_cart',function (e) {
    
        var cart_count = $('.navbar-tool-badge').text();
    cart_count = parseInt(cart_count);
    
    if($('input[type=radio][name=size]:checked').length == 0)
      {
         $('.msg').html('Please choose size.');
         return false;
      } else {
    var product_name = $('#hidden-name').val();
  var product_price = $('#hidden-price').val();
  var product_itemno = $('#itemno').val();
  var product_quantity = $('.quantity').val(); 
  var product_color = $('#color').val();
  var product_size = $("input[name='size']:checked").val();
  var sleeves = $('#sleeves').val();
  var neck = $('#neck').val();
e.preventDefault();
 
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "asset/includes/insertcart.php",
 data:{product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price, product_itemno:product_itemno , product_quantity:product_quantity, product_color:product_color, product_size:product_size, sleeves:sleeves, neck:neck},
cache: false,
success: function(response)
{
    load_cart_data();
    $("#getCode").html(response);
$("#myModal").modal('show');

// remove cart count
$('.navbar-tool-badge').html(cart_count + 1);

} 
});
}
 });
 
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
  var item_no = $(this).attr("id");
    var cart_count = $('.navbar-tool-badge').text();
    cart_count = parseInt(cart_count);
  
   $.ajax({
    url:"asset/includes/delete_item.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{item_no:item_no},
    success:function(data)
    {
        if(data){
            load_cart_data();
            $('#cart-popover').popover('hide');
        }

        // remove cart count
        $('.navbar-tool-badge').html(cart_count - 1);
        
    }
   })
});
 
});
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like an issue with your javascript not php. Please post the javascript code handling the ajax request and modal.

Comment: @LeviCole Sorry, it has been updating again. You can look this above mentioned.

Comment: You have a function in your ajax success called `load_cart_data();` what does this function do? Can you also include that code.

Comment: @LeviCole. I am really sorry to you. it has updated now. you can look this above mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the code provided, I can see the issue is in PHP. Please see my logic below.

```php
<?php

try {
    $stmt = $host->prepare( "SELECT * FROM productstock INNER JOIN product ON product.p_id = productstock.pid INNER JOIN productsize ON productsize.sid = productstock.size_id WHERE product.p_itemno = :itemno AND productsize.sname = :size" );
    $stmt->bindValue( ':itemno', $itemno );
    $stmt->bindValue( ':size', $size );
    $stmt->execute();

    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {

        // Current stock quantity
        $stockqty = $row[ 'stockqty' ];

        // No stock, bail early
        if ( !$stockqty ) {
            echo '<p>No available stock for that item.</p>';
        }

        // User didn't provide a quantity value
        else if ( !$qty ) {
            echo '<p>Please enter a quantity</p>';
        }

        // Lets add to the cart
        else {

            // Find product in cart
            $cartindex = array_search( $itemno, array_column( $_SESSION[ 'cart' ], 'item_no' ) );

            // Product info
            $product = null;

            // If already exists in cart
            if ( $cartindex !== false ) {
                $product = $_SESSION[ 'cart' ][ $cartindex ];
            }

            // Does not exit in cart, create new product info
            else {
                $product = [
                    'name'          => $name,
                    'price'         => $price,
                    'item_no'       => $itemno,
                    'qty'           => 0, // Default to none added
                    'color'         => $color,
                    'size'          => $size,
                    'stockitemno'   => $stockitemno,
                    'sleeves'       => $sleeves,
                    'neck'          => $neck,
                    'stockqty'      => $stockqty
                ];
            }

            // Track how many items were able to be added to the cart
            $totaladded = 0;

            // If users full amount is available
            if ( ( $product[ 'qty' ] + $qty ) <= $stockqty ) {
                $totaladded = $qty;
            }

            // Else add all available stock
            else if ( $stockqty - $product[ 'qty' ] ) {
                $totaladded = ( $stockqty - $product[ 'qty' ] );
            }

            // If we were able to add new items to cart
            if ( $totaladded ) {

                // Update product new qty
                $product[ 'qty' ] += $totaladded;

                // Update cart item
                if ( $cartindex !== false ) {
                    $_SESSION[ 'cart' ][ $cartindex ] = $product;
                }

                // Add new item to cart
                else {
                    $_SESSION[ 'cart' ][] = $product;
                }

                // Example: 5 item (size) were successfully added to your shopping cart.
                printf( '<p><strong>%d</strong> %s (%s)<br>was successfully added to your shopping cart.</p>', $totaladded, $name, $size );
            } else {
                echo '<p>Not enough stock</p>';
            }

        }

    }
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$host = null; 
$cart_count = count( $_SESSION[ 'cart' ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below logic, I hope this helps:

```
if (count($_SESSION['cart']) > 0) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $cart)
    {
        if (in_array($stockitemno, $cart)) {
            $exists = 1;
            $check = $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty'] + $qty;

            // add qty in cart with qty from post together
            // then check if the total is equal to or less
            // than your stockqty - if yes add qty together‚

            if($check <= $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['stockqty']){
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty'] += $qty;
            } 
            
            break;
        }

        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $cart)
        {
            if ($_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty'] >= $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['stockqty']) {
                echo "No More Stock";
            } else {
                echo $name . ' (' . $size . ')';
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<p>was successfully added to your shopping cart</p>";
            }
        }
       // if exists = 1
        if($exists !== 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['cart'][] = $product;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Total Stock: " . $qty . "</p>";
}
```